# Zend Framework 2 - Controller action return json

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I submit my form through ajax and if there are errors return json with them. But, when action return json model are appear this error:

> Inconsistent state; child view model is marked as terminal

That is my action:

```
$viewModel = new ViewModel();
$form = $sm->get('FormElementManager')->get('MyForm');

if ($request->isPost() && $request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
     $viewModel->setTerminal(true);
     $jsonModel = new JsonModel();

     try {
           if ($sm->get('MyService')->myFunction($form, $request->getPost())) {
               return $jsonModel->setVariables(array('var' => 'var1'));
           }
     } catch (\Exception $e) {
           return $jsonModel->setVariables(
                   array('errorMessage' => $e->getMessage())
           );
     }
}

return $viewModel->setVariables(array('form' => $form));
```

That is `my module.config.php`

```
'view_manager' => array(
   .....
   'strategies' => array(
       'ViewJsonStrategy',
   ),
)
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `$viewModel->setTerminal(true);`?

Answer (score 0):

You should not return your `$viewModel` but your `$jsonModel`.

By the way a `JsonModel` is set [as terminal by default](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-view/blob/master/src/Model/JsonModel.php#L38).

You should add `return $jsonModel` to your if clause.

Comment: I return `$viewModel`, because I need action template if form validators or filters find some problems with post data.